# Xamarin.Forms multi column table GUI

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, multiple-columns

Is ListView the right option to create a table? Something like this?

[image]

The cell content is text only, but I need to be able to show something like  a drop down menu on cell touch with the few most common options and text field for custom entry.

There will be a maximum of 80 to 100 lines of data, usually much less.

Comment: there are several free and commercial datagrid controls that work with XF

Comment: I found syncfusion data grid component, but I think it is overkill. I would prefer not to use 3rd party components.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ListView is indeed the best way to approximate a table.  Here is an example...

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listViewm" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListView.Header>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Switch" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="0" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="MediumBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
            <Label Text="Addend 1" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="MediumBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
            <Label Text="Addend 2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="MediumBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
            <Label Text="Result" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="MediumBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </ListView.Header>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text ="{Binding Switch}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text ="{Binding Addend1}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text ="{Binding Addend2}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Text ="{Binding Result}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This is the code in the view model...

```csharp
public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _switch = false;

    public bool Switch
    {
        get
        {
            return _switch;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_switch != value)
            {
                _switch = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Switch"));
            }
        }

    }

    public int Addend1 { get; set; }

    public int Addend2 { get; set; }

    public int Result
    {
        get
        {
            return Addend1 + Addend2;
        }
    }

    public string Summary
    {
        get
        {
            return Addend1 + " + " + Addend2 + " = " + Result;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

//...

public MyItems ObservableCollection<MyItem> { get; set; }

//...

MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
MyItems.Add(new MyItem() { Switch = true, Addend1 = 1, Addend2 = 2 });
MyItems.Add(new MyItem() { Switch = false, Addend1 = 1, Addend2 = 2 });
MyItems.Add(new MyItem() { Switch = true, Addend1 = 2, Addend2 = 3 });
MyItems.Add(new MyItem() { Switch = false, Addend1 = 2, Addend2 = 3 });
```

This results in a table that looks like this...

[image: ListView as table]

I am not sure why the gutters between columns are so wide.

You can define menu items on ViewCell.ContextActions.

Comment: You can set the grid's ColumnSpacing and RowSpacing to 0 to make the column "gutters" smaller.

Comment: and how to make sorting on columns?

Comment: Is it too late to ask a question here? Where is MyItems defined? I am trying to follow this example and I am getting a "type or namespace not found" on 'public MyItems ObservableCollection<MyItem> { get; set; }'.

Comment: @Charles.  There is a typo in my answer above.  Should be public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }

Comment: @AQuirky Aha! Thanks! I guessed that but am struggling with other issues so I was not sure.