# Xamarin.Forms Create dynamic, unbound columns from "simple" List

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For an assignment where we turn a website into a Xamarin.Forms app,

I need to display tabular data to the user where I get all the data (that is, both Column Headers and the data fields themselves) from the REST API; I just need to show it (so, I basically have a fully populated two-dimensional array of data that I need to show to the user).

Now, I have found [multiple](https://www.devexpress.com/products/xamarin/grid/) [DataGrid](https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid) libraries and also [a way to display tables in "vanilla" Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870535/xamarin-forms-multi-column-table-gui) (as there doesn't seem to be a Table component), but as far as I can tell, these all were mostly made for bound data where the columns are already defined *and* there's a "real" class where the data comes from.

As I said, that is not really the case for me as the data is wholly coming from the provided REST API.

So, finally my question:

How do I best create a Xamarin.Forms table with dynamically defined, unbound columns and populate that table from a two-dimensional array structure?

I have to add that I'm new to both C# and Xamarin - but I have proper programming experience in several other languages, including Java.