# ListView Cell Binding not finding Methods in Collection

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am trying to use [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) and ListView for the first time. I am working from *[Xamarin.Forms multi column table GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870535/xamarin-forms-multi-column-table-gui)*

My ViewModel looks like this:

```csharp
public class CodeTableViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public static ObservableCollection<CodeTableRow> CodeTable { get; set; }

    public CodeTableViewModel()
    {
    }

    public class CodeTableRow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        int codePoint;

        public CodeTableRow(int point)
        {
            codePoint = point;
        }

        public string Decimal
        {
            get
            {
                return codePoint.ToString("D");
            }
        }

        public string Hex
        {
            get
            {
                return codePoint.ToString("X2");
            }
        }

        public string Ascii
        {
            get
            {
                return ((char)codePoint).ToString();
            }
        }
...
```

My XAML looks like this

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:RefCard.ViewModels"
             x:Class="RefCard.Views.CodeTablePage"
             Title="Code Table">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:DataType="viewmodels:CodeTableViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding CodeTable}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="Dec" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="0"   FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="MediumBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
                    <Label Text="Hex" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="MediumBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
                    <Label Text="ASCII" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="MediumBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text ="{Binding Decimal}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text ="{Binding Hex}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0"></Label>
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text ="{Binding Ascii}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0"></Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In the page constructor I do `CodeTableViewModel.CodeTable = new ObservableCollection<CodeTableViewModel.CodeTableRow>();` and a bunch of Add's.

I have tried hacking a bunch of variations, but the basic error is:

> XFC0045 Binding: Property "Decimal" not found on "RefCard.ViewModels.CodeTableViewModel". RefCard C:\Users\Charles\source\repos\RefCard\RefCard\Views\CodeTablePage.xaml 38

How do I resolve that?

Comment: 1) get rid of `x:DataType="viewmodels:CodeTableViewModel"`, 2) the class definition for `CodeTableRow` should not be nested inside `CodeTableViewModel`, 3) `CodeTableViewModel` should initialize it's owner properties in the constructor, the page should not be doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, [Jason have provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67913143/listview-cell-binding-not-finding-methods-in-collection#comment120038843_67913143) three suggestions for you.

Firstly, you don't need to add `x:DataType="viewmodels:CodeTableViewModel"`, because the ListView's ItemsSource="{Binding CodeTable}", then CodeTable list of CodeTableRow.

Secondly, from this document [Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm),

**View**—The view is responsible for defining the structure, layout, and appearance of what the user sees on screen.

**ViewModel**—The view model implements properties and commands to which the view can data bind to, and notifies the view of any state changes through change notification events.

**Model**—Model classes are non-visual classes that encapsulate the app's data.

So I suggest you don't add the Model class in your ViewModel class. These are two independent classes.

```csharp
public class CodeTableViewModel
{
    public  ObservableCollection<CodeTableRow> CodeTable { get; set; }

    public CodeTableViewModel()
    {
        CodeTable = new ObservableCollection<CodeTableRow>();
    }
}

public class CodeTableRow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    int codePoint;

    public CodeTableRow(int point)
    {
        codePoint = point;
    }

    public string Decimal
    {
        get
        {
            return codePoint.ToString("D");
        }
    }

    public string Hex
    {
        get
        {
            return codePoint.ToString("X2");
        }
    }

    public string Ascii
    {
        get
        {
            return ((char)codePoint).ToString();
        }
    }
 }
```

Usually, we get some data in ViewModel class, then binding ViewModel to current contentPage's BindingContext.

```csharp
public class CodeTableViewModel
{
    public  ObservableCollection<CodeTableRow> CodeTable { get; set; }

    public CodeTableViewModel()
    {
        CodeTable = new ObservableCollection<CodeTableRow>()
        {
            new CodeTableRow(12),
            new CodeTableRow(18),
            new CodeTableRow(19),
            new CodeTableRow(121),
            new CodeTableRow(124)
        };

    }
}

public Page22()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.BindingContext = new CodeTableViewModel();
}
```

If you still want to get data in ContentPage's constructor, you can take a look the following code, but I don't suggest it.

```csharp
public partial class Page22 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CodeTableViewModel _viewmodel;

    public CodeTableViewModel viewmodel
    {
        get { return _viewmodel; }
        set
        {
            _viewmodel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("viewmodel");
        }
    }

    public Page22()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewmodel = new CodeTableViewModel();

        viewmodel.CodeTable = new ObservableCollection<CodeTableRow>()
        {
            new CodeTableRow(12),
            new CodeTableRow(18),
            new CodeTableRow(19),
            new CodeTableRow(121),
            new CodeTableRow(124)
        };

        this.BindingContext = viewmodel;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, it is the **incorrect data type** for your ListView items.

1. Define your model in an individual class
   (there isn't any need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for model classes, but do that in BaseViewModel)

   ```csharp
   namespace YourProj.Models
   {
       public class CodeTableRow
       {
           public string Decimal { get; set; }
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Define property of CodeTableRow in CodeTableViewModel

   ```csharp
   public class CodeTableViewModel : BaseViewModel
   {
       public static ObservableCollection<CodeTableRow> CodeTable { get; set; }
       public CodeTableViewModel()
       {
       }

       private CodeTableRow _codeTableRow;
       public CodeTableRow CodeTableRow
       {
           get => _codeTableRow;
           set => SetProperty(ref _codeTableRow, value);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Correct the DataType for your ListView items

   ```xml
   <ContentPage
       xmlns:models="clr-namespace:YourProj.Models"
       ...>
   <ListView ...>
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CodeTableRow">
           ....
   </ListView>
   ```

Comment: I did everything suggested above and below (NOT the "if you still want to get data ...:).

1. I am getting the error "The type 'models:CodeTableRow' was not found ..." 2. I am getting the error "Cannot resolve type "models:CodeTableRow". 3. I am getting an IntelliSense error on the ListView Binding "No Data Context found for CodeTable" -- that is what had led me to add the x:DataType (and had made the error go away).

Comment: Got it! Missed some of the above. Thank you all. I will try to not take this as just a rote answer but try to learn MVVM organization from it.